# How to plot exciton wave function with phase information?

Tags: gw-bse

In GW-BSE calculations, people could analyze the exciton wave function $|S\rangle$ by plotting the BSE eigenvector $A_{cv\mathbf{k}}$ that satisfies $|S\rangle = \sum_{cv\mathbf{k}}A_{cv\mathbf{k}}|cv\rangle$. In genreal, $A_{cv\mathbf{k}}$ is complex number, usually the modulus or squared modulus is plotted. I'm wondering how to add the phase information on the plot like Fig. 10 in [PRB 93, 235435 (2016)](https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.93.235435).

[image: exciton wave function]

Comment: This data is calculated with the BerkelyGW package?

Comment: Yambo has a tutorial about it: http://www.yambo-code.org/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_analyse_excitons

Comment: Yes, it is calculated by BGW. The Yambo tutorial is about plotting exciton in real space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a small script for BGW to do the plot https://github.com/BerkeleyGW/bgwtools/blob/master/bgwtools/BSE/plot_envelope.py.

Comment: Have you figured out the phase problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think these figures are plotting the square of $A_{vc\vec{k}}$, therefore no phase information is contained in these figures. Note that the figures that you are showing are marking each excitonic state with $s$, $p$, $d$, and $f$, which represent exactly the square of the wave function in the problem of the hydrogen atom.

The exciton character and composition in reciprocal space is given by the so-called exciton weights

\begin{equation}
\omega_{v\vec{k}}^\lambda=\sum_c |A_{vc\vec{k}}^\lambda|^2 \tag{1}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\omega_{c\vec{k}}^\lambda=\sum_v |A_{vc\vec{k}}^\lambda|^2 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
which contain information about the BSE eigenvectors and represent the contributions to a given electronic transition to the $\lambda$th solution of the BSE.

- Ref: [Phys. Rev. Materials 3, 074001](https://journals.aps.org/prmaterials/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevMaterials.3.074001)

Comment: The overall shape can be obtained by the A squared. But where do the negative values come from?

Comment: @XiaomingWang I can't figure out that :)

Comment: Let's see if anyone has experience with that.

Comment: In the figure, the blue and red denotes the phases, so it is not squared. They look like real-valued versions of the wave-function, though, not the complex valued.

Comment: @Greg The wave-function are complex valued fore sure.

Comment: @XiaomingWang Those figures are identical to the non-complex valued H atom wavefunctions (e.g px, py.. instead of p+, p-) , so they are the real valued version (as the whole point of the figure is to illustrate the similarity to H atom real valued functions)